# Why cat redirect somtimes uses CR and sometimes LF for line end

Tags: bash, newline, io-redirection

when I paste the following into the console:

```
cat >test
test1
test11
```

the resulting file has CR (0x0d) as a line break
if I do

```
cat >test
```

and then paste the content:

```
test1
test11
```

I get LF (0x0a) as a line break character.

Can anyone tell me why these behave differently
I am using ubuntu 20.04 and have tried different terminals (not sure if that makes a difference)
That also happens on other hosts when used over ssh.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't `cat`, but the string input. This is because you don't use any [here-doc](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) (in order to properly represent that string having multiple lines) and you either terminate the line or have some line-wraps. The output usually always equals the input ...that is just alike <kbd>Enter</kbd> vs. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Just paste that into any text-editor capable of displaying non-printable characters and you'd see.

Comment: When I  display the text with non-printables I see that control characters (namely 0x0d and 0x0a) but in both scenarios, I paste multi-line string, in the first case that includes the command to execute in the second I call the command manually but paste the whole multi-line content in one go. After your comment I realize it's not a cat issue and I know how to use here-doc however I still don't understand why this string is treated differently if copied as two parts versus one.

Comment: This might come from how the terminal has to represent the line-wraps and breaks (without executing the command after the first line already), without a here-doc (and this also is the reason why they even came up with here-docs). Not sure if there's any documentation why it is implemented alike this, so far I just assumed this to be a "given" reality.